# Tool to calculate total returns of a mutual fund over a given time period?

Tags: stocks, investing, mutual-funds, websites

I am interested in calculating the total returns of a particular mutual fund (GSCGX) over a given time period (feb 12 2010 to feb 12 2020), including reinvestments of dividends and capital gains. I have found, on various websites, a history of the Net Asset Value and of all distributions, and technically I could piece these numbers together, weighing the distributions over time so that they grow at the same rate as the fund.

Yet, I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Does anyone know of a website/tool that allows one to calculate the total return (or annualized return) over a given time period? This would save so much time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are specifically off-topic here. Sorry.

Comment: OP is asking whether a tool exists to calculate total returns instead of NAVs, no specific product/service recommendation is requested; OP gives a very specific question with an exact example of what they're trying to achieve. This could be answered without even referring to a specific product, or instead a list of products could be provided for balance. There's plenty of people new to the field who might be looking to resolve the same challenge. OP maybe consider rewording to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a tool does already exist; it's called a **Portfolio Manager**. They're often provided by fund data/research providers and newspapers. Possibly you've come across one but maybe not fully appreciated the nuances behind its operation.

Primarily a Portfolio Manager has two modes of operation; it can be a **transactional** portfolio or **watchlist** portfolio:

- A **watchlist** portfolio is used to build a list of potential funds to keep an eye on; they usually show the trailing total returns (i.e. 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1Y, YTD etc) up to the latest price (current date or T-1 for OEICs/Unit Trusts).
- A **transactional** portfolio is used to build up a list of historic transactions to derive a *personal return*. It gives you (or at least should have the option to give you) the total return from the transaction start; including each of the distributions and subsequent reinvestments based on the closing NAV on the day of the distribution reinvestment.

[image: Total return for GSCGX; Feb 12 2010 - Feb 12 2020]

From your question, you'll need a **transactional** portfolio to specify your "transaction" dates. The image shows the given fund's automatically derived distribution reinvestments based on a pair of buy/sell transactions from the dates provided.

In the interest of not violating community rules I'm not going to give you a product recommendation; however if you Google "*Leading fund provider portfolio manager*", this should give you an impartial list (ignoring the ads) of portfolio managers from the larger data providers. NB. I would advocate avoiding any "Mickey Mouse" home-grown portfolio managers as they might not quite implement the complexity required in order to derive the compounded total returns for which you're looking.

Comment: If you're going to downvote an answer, please specify why or suggest an edit to the answer. OP is a new poster; I'm a new answer provider. It's unproductive and a deterrent to new users to cast a downvote without providing any constructive criticism or guidance.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the OP asks for website/tool recommendations which is off topic here. You say in your comment under the OP that "This could be answered without even referring to a specific product" and then post about a specific product. Not sure how that's not a recommendation and there I'm not sure how it's not off-topic as well.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

Comment: @Nosjack thanks for the info. Admittedly might not be the best wording (it is OP's first post) however some may need to take time to read OP's question. OP doesn't ask for a specific website/recommendation; OP asks whether such software exists. Similarly no product referred to in my answer - nothing product specific with the exception of the screenshot - all branding removed. I discussed generalised portfolio management software concepts; could have pasted in a screenshot from any product - I literally just picked the first one in Google and made a new portfolio. Never used it before.